# TYPO3 - May I include FlexForm XML file like nested?

Tags: xml, nested, include, typo3, flexform

Is there a solution to include XML file into T3DataStructure, like nested tabs?
This is what i have tried but didn't works.

What I want is, when I press Add Links button, to get Link.xml file structure shown, that i can input content in that fields.

```
<link>
<section>1</section>
<type>array</type>
<title>Include Link.XML</title>
<el>
    <container>
        <title>Links</title>
        <type>array</type>
        <el>
            <includeLinks>
                <label>Add Link</label>
                <config>
                    <ds>
                        <default>FILE:EXT:theme/Configuration/FlexForms/Content/Link.xml</default>
                    </ds>
                </config>
            </includeLinks>
        </el>
    </container>
</el>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is something like `inline relational record editing` aka `IRRE` for FlexForms. This is called `sections` and you can find an example here:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Flex/Examples.html?highlight=section#a-flex-form-field-with-two-flex-section-containers

Comment: Yes, but I am looking for a solution, so that the xml structure of one element in nested elements is in a separate xml file. 
I want something like when i click Add Link, to show me whole xml structure from another file. With that solution i want to separate elements of page, and just include them when I need them. It is a little bit complicated because of my bad english, but i hope that you will understand me. However, thank you for your answer.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible to include another DataStructure on demand form within a DataStructure, so the only option you've got is to go for the sections I mentioned before.

Comment: On the other hand you might want to reconsider that, because a link is actually content and not just a configuration parameter. Since FlexForms are stored as XML content in the database there are several concerns that would recommend using them for configurational purposes only and stick to normalized DB relations for real content instead. In your case this would be an IRRE field for the links pointing to a table with link records.